# How can I scrape a table data that includes both plain text and text in "double quotes"?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape data from zone-h.org web page. First, I bypassed the web page captcha error by adding cookies in the script. Then I scrape the table with BeautifulSoup and store the table. One of the column, however, doesn't have plain text; the information exists in a quote ("...").

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "http://www.zone-h.org/archive/filter=1/published=0/domain=twitter/fulltext=1/page=1?"
cookie = {'PHPSESSID': 'XXXXXXXXXXX','ZHE':'XXXXXXXXXXXX'}
response = requests.post(url, cookies=cookie)
print(response)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df_domain = pd.DataFrame(df)
df_domain.head()
```

How can I get the data from L (Location) column? The source of this column is;

```
<td><img src="/images/cflags/png/us.png" alt="United States" title="United States"></td>
```

What do you advise to getting the data (United States) from title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data from the column, it's necessary to iterate over the table row by row and grab the data from `<img>` attribute `title=`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.zone-h.org/archive/filter=1/published=0/domain=twitter/fulltext=1/page=1?"
cookie = {'PHPSESSID': 'XXX','ZHE':'XXX'}
response = requests.post(url, cookies=cookie)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')

rows = []
for tr in soup.select('tr')[:-2]:
    row = []
    for td in tr.select('td'):
        if td.text.strip():
            row.append(td.text.strip())
        else:
            img = td.select_one('img[title]')
            if img:
                row.append(img['title'])
            else:
                row.append('')
    rows.append(row)

from textwrap import shorten
print(''.join('{: <20}'.format(d) for d in rows[0]))
for row in rows[1:]:
    print(''.join('{: <20}'.format(shorten(d, 20)) for d in row))
```

The final table is in variable `rows`. You can import it into pandas.
To print it to the screen:

```
Time                Notifier            H                   M                   R                   L                                       Domain              OS                  View                
2019/02/11          RxR                                                                                                                     [...]               Linux               mirror              
2019/01/24          Al1ne3737           H                                                           United States                           twitterlike.com.br  Linux               mirror              
2019/01/23          Psycho Crew         H                                                           Cyprus                                  [...]               Unknown             mirror              
2018/08/11          Iran is winner trump                                        R                   United States                           [...]               Unknown             mirror              
2018/05/08          İllegalHackerz                                                                  Turkey                                  [...]               MacOSX              mirror              
2018/01/04          BIGM4N                                                      R                   United States                           [...]               Unknown             mirror              
2017/09/27          Mr.str3_at                                                                      United States                           [...]               Linux               mirror              
2017/08/02          SkullZ                                                      R                   United States                           [...]               Unknown             mirror              
2017/07/21          Dex hacker          H                                                           United States                           cdn- [...]          Linux               mirror              
2017/07/21          Dex hacker          H                                                           United States                           [...]               Linux               mirror              
2017/07/08          KusterAttacker      H                                                           France                                  [...]               Linux               mirror              
2017/05/22          GeNErAL                                                                         United States                           [...]               Linux               mirror              
2017/02/11          SA3D HaCk3D                                                                     United States                           [...]               Linux               mirror              
2017/02/07          SA3D HaCk3D                                                                     United States                           [...]               Linux               mirror              
2017/02/06          SA3D HaCk3D                                                                     Netherlands                             [...]               Linux               mirror              
2017/02/06          Imam                                                                            Netherlands                             [...]               Linux               mirror              
2017/02/06          BALA SNIPER                                                                     United States                           [...]               Linux               mirror              
2016/11/12          jrb                 H                                                           Indonesia                               twitter.co.mz       Linux               mirror              
2016/09/22          ..:<h1>:..          H                                                           United States                           twitter.net         Linux               mirror              
2016/07/03          ByNemesis           H                                                           Turkey                                  twitterdukkan.com   Linux               mirror              
2016/07/01          Hmei7               H                                       R                   United States                           twitter.com         Unknown             mirror              
2016/06/08          WoKaBoYa            H                                                           United States                           [...]               Linux               mirror              
2016/01/02          Akıncılar                                                                       Turkey                                  [...]               Linux               mirror              
2015/12/27          ScAmA               H                                                           United States                           www.twitter-ar.com  Linux               mirror              
2015/09/24          Hacked By [...]     H                                                           United States                           ikilltwitter.com    Win 2003            mirror
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the 'L' column in your DataFrame is empty or cannot be used to retrieve the Location value you need, I would analyze the entire table using BeautifulSoup, iterating on the values `<tr>` and `<td>` to create the DataFrame from scratch.